# Currency Symbol Doubles When Converting Number to Text in Formula Field

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to convert number to formatted string using a formula field. Conversion is from USD (which is the default org currency) to JPY. I didn't use the standard multi-currency function offered by Salesforce as it has limitations when it comes to custom objects and I don't want to have a problem with it on my future implementations.

Result of first testing is correct, given the ff. values for each field:

**Correct:**

```
USD_to_JPY_Rate__c (number field)
107.0000

Currency_Field__c (currency field)
$2,000.00

Converted Currency_Field__c (USD-JPY)
¥214,000.00
```

On my second testing, I changed `Currency_Field__c` value to `$25,000.00`, but I got ff. result:

**Wrong:**

```
Currency_Field__c (currency field)
$25,000.00

Converted Currency_Field__c (USD-JPY)
¥2,¥675,000.00
```

How can I correct this? Below is the formula:

**Converted Currency_Field__c (USD-JPY)**

```
IF( NOT( ISBLANK( USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) ) ,
IF(( Currency_Field__c * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) >= 1000000,
'¥' & TEXT(FLOOR(( Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) / 1000000)) & ",",
"") &
IF(( Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) >= 1000,
'¥' & RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(( Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) / 1000)), 3) & ",",
"") &
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(( Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ))), 3) & "." &
IF(MOD(( Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) , 1) * 100 < 10,
"0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(( Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) , 1), 2) * 100),
TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(( Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ) , 1), 2) * 100, 99))
), '¥0.00')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the currency symbol only *before* the first IF block in the TRUE part.

```
IF(
    NOT ISBLANK( USD_to_JPY_Rate__c ),
    '¥' & IF(
        Currency_Field__c * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c >= 1000000,
        TEXT(FLOOR(Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c / 1000000)) & ",", 
        ""
    ) &
    IF(
        Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c >= 1000,
        RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c / 1000)), 3) & ",",
        ""
    ) &
    RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c )), 3) & "." &
    IF(
        MOD(Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c, 1) * 100 < 10,
        "0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c , 1), 2) * 100),
        TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(Currency_Field * USD_to_JPY_Rate__c , 1), 2) * 100, 99))
    ), 
    '¥0.00'
)
```

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Modified the formula and it is working now. Thanks for the immediate response and help!